# Distributed Keras MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy doesn't work with embedding_column converts from variable-length input feature

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, distributed-tensorflow

I am trying TensorFlow 2.0 and testing the distributed solution of keras, but I face a problems:

`embedding_column` converts from `variable-length input feature` doesn't work with Distributed Keras `MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy` . **With local training(non-distributed), everything is fine , or if I convert variable-length input feature to `indicator_column` everything is ok too.**

here is the code to reproduce the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import json

os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps({
    'cluster': {
        'worker': ["localhost:12345", "localhost:23456"]
    },
    'task': {'type': 'worker', 'index': 1} # {'type': 'worker', 'index': 0}
})

# create fake dataset file
def serialize_example(value):
    feature = {
      'color': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=value)),
    }
    example_proto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    return example_proto.SerializeToString()

tfrecord_writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter('./color.tfrecord')
for each in [['G', 'R'], ['B'], ['B', 'G'], ['R']]:
    tfrecord_writer.write(serialize_example(each))
tfrecord_writer.close()

# build feature column
color_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('color', ['R', 'G', 'B'], dtype=tf.string)
color_embeding = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(color_column, 4) # tf.feature_column.indicator_column(color_column)

inputs = {}
inputs['color'] = tf.keras.layers.Input(name='color', shape=(None, ), sparse=True, dtype='string')

# build model
with tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy().scope():
    dense = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures([color_embeding])(inputs)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, output)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# build dataset
def parse(example_proto):
    feature_description = {
        'color': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string)
    }
    parsed_features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)
    return parsed_features, True

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('./color.tfrecord').map(parse).repeat().batch(1)

model.fit(dataset, epochs=3, steps_per_epoch=1)
```

ERROR LOG:

```
2019-10-14 22:35:48.491329: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-10-14 22:35:48.504154: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fd065e01d50 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-10-14 22:35:48.504171: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2019-10-14 22:35:48.506239: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:258] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> localhost:12345, 1 -> localhost:23456}
2019-10-14 22:35:48.506975: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:365] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:23456
INFO:tensorflow:Enabled multi-worker collective ops with available devices: ['/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/device:CPU:0', '/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/device:XLA_CPU:0']
INFO:tensorflow:Multi-worker CollectiveAllReduceStrategy with cluster_spec = {u'worker': [u'localhost:12345', u'localhost:23456']}, task_type = 'worker', task_id = 1, num_workers = 2, local_devices = ('/job:worker/task:1',), communication = CollectiveCommunication.AUTO
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Running Distribute Coordinator with mode = 'independent_worker', cluster_spec = {u'worker': [u'localhost:12345', u'localhost:23456']}, task_type = u'worker', task_id = 1, environment = None, rpc_layer = 'grpc'
WARNING:tensorflow:`eval_fn` is not passed in. The `worker_fn` will be used if an "evaluator" task exists in the cluster.
WARNING:tensorflow:`eval_strategy` is not passed in. No distribution strategy will be used for evaluation.
INFO:tensorflow:Multi-worker CollectiveAllReduceStrategy with cluster_spec = {u'worker': [u'localhost:12345', u'localhost:23456']}, task_type = u'worker', task_id = 1, num_workers = 2, local_devices = (u'/job:worker/task:1',), communication = CollectiveCommunication.AUTO
INFO:tensorflow:Multi-worker CollectiveAllReduceStrategy with cluster_spec = {u'worker': [u'localhost:12345', u'localhost:23456']}, task_type = u'worker', task_id = 1, num_workers = 2, local_devices = (u'/job:worker/task:1',), communication = CollectiveCommunication.AUTO
WARNING:tensorflow:ModelCheckpoint callback is not provided. Workers will need to restart training if any fails.
2019-10-14 22:36:00.226012: W tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/data/auto_shard.cc:400] Cannot find shardable dataset, adding a shard node at the end of the dataset instead. This may have performance implications.
Train for 1 steps
Epoch 1/3
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 2 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce for IndexedSlices: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 2 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce for IndexedSlices: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
INFO:tensorflow:Collective batch_all_reduce: 1 all-reduces, num_workers = 2
2019-10-14 22:36:01.352450: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/ring_alg.cc:279] Aborting RingReduce with Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.352478: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.352638: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/ring_alg.cc:279] Aborting RingGather with Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.352657: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353012: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/ring_alg.cc:279] Aborting RingGather with Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353029: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353213: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/ring_alg.cc:279] Aborting RingReduce with Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353225: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353325: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at collective_ops.cc:234 : Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353338: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/ring_alg.cc:279] Aborting RingReduce with Cancelled: [_Derived_]Cancelled
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352818000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Cancelled","grpc_status":1}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353352: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Cancelled: [_Derived_]Cancelled
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352818000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Cancelled","grpc_status":1}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353370: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at collective_ops.cc:125 : Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353359: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
     [[metrics/accuracy/div_no_nan/allreduce_1/CollectiveReduce]]
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353469: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/ring_alg.cc:279] Aborting RingReduce with Cancelled: [_Derived_]Cancelled
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352917000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Cancelled","grpc_status":1}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353451: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at collective_ops.cc:234 : Cancelled: [_Derived_]Cancelled
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352818000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Cancelled","grpc_status":1}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353491: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Cancelled: [_Derived_]Cancelled
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352917000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Cancelled","grpc_status":1}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353512: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at collective_ops.cc:234 : Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353630: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at collective_ops.cc:234 : Cancelled: [_Derived_]Cancelled
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352917000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Cancelled","grpc_status":1}
2019-10-14 22:36:01.353698: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at collective_ops.cc:125 : Internal: Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[{{node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1}}]]","grpc_status":13}
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b83aa9a3e019> in <module>()
     43
     44 dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('./color.tfrecord').map(parse).repeat().batch(1)
---> 45 model.fit(dataset, epochs=3, steps_per_epoch=1)

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.pyc in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729
    730   def evaluate(self,

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.pyc in fit(self, *args, **kwargs)
    787   def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):
    788     return train_with_multi_worker(self._single_worker_loop.fit)(
--> 789         *args, **kwargs)
    790
    791   def evaluate(self, *args, **kwargs):

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.pyc in wrapper(model, **kwargs)
    774         _worker_fn,
    775         model._distribution_strategy,
--> 776         mode=dc.CoordinatorMode.INDEPENDENT_WORKER)
    777
    778   return wrapper

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_coordinator.pyc in run_distribute_coordinator(worker_fn, strategy, eval_fn, eval_strategy, mode, cluster_spec, task_type, task_id, session_config, rpc_layer)
    851         # All jobs run `worker_fn` if between-graph.
    852         return _run_single_worker(worker_fn, strategy, cluster_spec, task_type,
--> 853                                   task_id, session_config, rpc_layer)
    854       else:
    855         # Only one node runs `worker_fn` if in-graph.

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_coordinator.pyc in _run_single_worker(worker_fn, strategy, cluster_spec, task_type, task_id, session_config, rpc_layer, worker_barrier, coord)
    358         return worker_fn(strategy)
    359     else:
--> 360       return worker_fn(strategy)
    361
    362

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.pyc in _worker_fn(_)
    769       filtered_callbacks = dist_utils.filter_distributed_callbacks(callbacks)
    770       kwargs['callbacks'] = filtered_callbacks
--> 771       return method(model, **kwargs)
    772
    773     return dc.run_distribute_coordinator(

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.pyc in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.pyc in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.pyc in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87
     88   return execution_function

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.pyc in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    518         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    519         # stateless function.
--> 520         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    521     else:
    522       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1821     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   1822     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 1823     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1824
   1825   @property

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.pyc in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1139          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1140                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1141         self.captured_inputs)
   1142
   1143   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.pyc in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1222     if executing_eagerly:
   1223       flat_outputs = forward_function.call(
-> 1224           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1225     else:
   1226       gradient_name = self._delayed_rewrite_functions.register()

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.pyc in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    509               inputs=args,
    510               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 511               ctx=ctx)
    512         else:
    513           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.pyc in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

/Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.pyc in raise_from(value, from_value)
    735 else:
    736     def raise_from(value, from_value):
--> 737         raise value
    738
    739

InternalError:  Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].
     [[node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1 (defined at /Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]]
Additional GRPC error information:
{"created":"@1571063761.352390000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Inconsistent output shapes, got [4], but expected is [2].\n\t [[node Adam/allreduce_1/CollectiveGather_1 (defined at /Users/felix/Envs/tf2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]]","grpc_status":13}
     [[metrics/accuracy/div_no_nan/allreduce_1/CollectiveReduce]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_1149]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

**This problem has been bothering me for a week, any help will be appreciated**

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `steps_per_epochs` parameter. For some reason, Keras (or TF) doesn't know how to figure out the dataset size when training on tfrecords.

EDIT: Actually i just checked the newly updated TF 2.0 Documentation right now, it appears that now Dataset creation needs to be within the `strategy.scope()`. Check https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras#train_the_model_with_multiworker